# javascript: How to load part of a page first

Tags: javascript, html, css

Most native apps(e.g. iOS) have a welcome page to help people to wait while the app is loading.

I'm developing a `ruby on rails` web app, (`website`!)

And I want to add a `welcome page` to my web app as well. So when users feel better when waiting for the loading of the web app.

A `welcome page` is comprised of its own `html`, `css` and `js`. How can I make them loaded first and then silently loading the remaining page?

Comment: This Welcome screen is called Splash Screen.Plz first tell that for which platform u r developing Android or  ios or a simple HTML....eg The splash Screen is Conrolled by handler or Thread in android .....(java)...If u are developing HTML app you can change Welcome screen using javascipt or ajax...whatever u like......

Comment: @AnuragGoel, My fault. I thought `web app` refers to the websites that look like an `app`. This is for `websites`.

Comment: OK ! so u can use javascipt (ajax) for doing that......u can trigger an event...to load another page...after loading  of welcome screen......

Answer (score 2):

iHateTomatoes has a [tutorial](https://ihatetomatoes.net/create-custom-preloading-screen) that teaches you how to make a preloader with CSS3 and JavaScript.

Comment: Just read about that. It uses `setTimeout` to delay the overall page display. Not a very direct approach I feel? Or it is not that fast.

Comment: Read right above the `setTimeout` code snippet: "Because we don’t have enough “heavy” content on our page, we will be faking the loading of the content with a simple jQuery." They are using `setTimeout` so that you can see the results.

Comment: @jsve. My fault. I read it again. I think the proper solution is `preloader` it mentioned. But that seems mainly for `assets`(image, sound), not too much written about `html` elements.

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't want the loading page be it's own html, css and js. That would defeat the purpose of having a website that loads quickly. 
Instead, add a fixed positioned div on top of your current site that would contain your preloader animation and hide the main part of the site with CSS. Then, using something like imageReady plugin, get a callback of when all the images have loaded, at which point you can unhide the main site, hide the loader div and display a loaded page. It's easy to make it into a reusable solution that would work the same way on all the pages of your site.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a web-app you might try starting from the Firefox WebIDE examples:

From Tools -> Web Developer -> WebIDE you can create an example app, they make script load after the page shows with:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js" defer></script>
```